# Unable to logout in spring security using angular client

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have the following spring security configuration:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/login").authenticated()
              .antMatchers("/newGame").authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic().and().formLogin().loginPage("/unauthorizedRedirect").and().logout();
}
```

On "register" i am creating a new user account.
The purpose of "login" is to let spring security authenticate a user using http basic.The client sends an Authorization token that is automatically used by spring to validate the user and to create the session.After the call to this method, the browser sets the JSESSION id cookie.
The loginPage "unauthorizedRedirect" is used as a way to handle unauthorized requests.If a request is unauthorized, spring will redirect that call to "unauthorizedRedirect" where i simply return an 401 error on client.

```
    @GetMapping("/unauthorizedRedirect")
    public ResponseEntity redirectTo() {
       return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
  }
```

My problem is when i try to logout.The client call looks like this:

```
    this.httpClient.get(environment.backendAddress + '/logout', {withCredentials: 
        true}).subscribe(data => {
    });
```

I am using "withCredentials:sure" to send the cookies along with the HttpRequest.
On the logout call i get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/unauthorizedRedirect?logout 401
2019-12-28 22:48:52.440 DEBUG 14240 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : 
Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/logout'
2019-12-28 22:48:52.440 DEBUG 14240 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : 
matched
2019-12-28 22:48:52.440 DEBUG 14240 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : 
Logging out user 
'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@a287bf64: 
Principal: com.arena.core.config.auth.CustomUserDetails@5d78f3c4; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; 
Authenticated: true; Details: 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities' and transferring to logout 
destination
2019-12-28 22:48:52.440 DEBUG 14240 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.l.SecurityContextLogoutHandler : 
Invalidating session: 3847D2803AFEA2656C6CE69BF253FCAB
```

After some logs i see

```
2019-12-28 22:48:52.467 DEBUG 14240 --- [io-8080-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : 
No HttpSession currently exists
2019-12-28 22:48:52.467 DEBUG 14240 --- [io-8080-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : 
No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
```

I forgot to mention that the angular client makes three requests :
[image]

I guess that the first call invalidates the session and the second tries to call an resource that is secured and it failes since there is no valid session.Is this right?
How do i fix this?

Also, the logout works using Postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After logout, Spring Security redirects you to login page. Give this login page proper rights:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/unauthorizedRedirect").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/login").authenticated()
              .antMatchers("/newGame").authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic().and().formLogin().loginPage("/unauthorizedRedirect").and().logout();
}
```